# Detecting the existence of an element in a subarray with specific properties

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

If I have an array that looks like this:

```
testArray = 
  {{"StringOne", 3.444}, {"StringOne", 433}, {"StringOne", 1}, {"StringOne", 8}, 
   {"StringOne", 1}, {"StringOne", 5}, {"StringOne", 2}, {"StringOne", 1}, 
   {"StringOne", 9}, {"StringOne", 1}, {"StringTwo", 7.64}, {"StringTwo", 34}, 
   {"StringTwo", 6}, {"StringTwo", 99}, {"StringTwo", 54}, {"StringTwo", 12.33}, 
   {"StringTwo", 6}, {"StringTwo", 7}, {"StringTwo", 76}, {"StringTwo", 1}};
```

I want to quickly detect the existence of a subarray of the form: `{"StringTwo", n}` for all $n > k$ (for some real-valued $n$ and $k$).

How can I best do this?

Comment: `Select` & `Cases`

Comment: `Cases[testArray, {_, x_} /; x > 75]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Position[testArray, "StringTwo"]
{{11, 1}, {12, 1}, {13, 1}, {14, 1}, {15, 1}, {16, 1}, {17, 1}, 
 {18, 1}, {19, 1}, {20, 1}}
```

or can test for the presence of an element using

```
MemberQ[testArray, "StringTwo", 2]
True
```

Adding in the extra parameter $k$, we can test whether any of the second elements are larger than $k$ using:

```
Length[Select[
   First@Rest@
     Transpose[
      testArray[[First@
         Transpose@Position[testArray, "StringTwo"]]]], # > k &]] > 0
```

Replace `k` by 9 and you get True. Replace `k` by 100 and you get False as expected. Of course you would probably want to make this into a function for easy use. Somewhat more concisely, you could use:

```
Select[testArray, (#[[1]] == "StringTwo") && (#[[2]] > 9) &] != {}
```

which directly checks if there are any elements of testArray with first element equal to "stringTwo" and second element that is > k.

Comment: I'm just trying to quickly determine if there exists some element in that larger array of the form: {"StringTwo",n} where "n" is some integer or real number > k (an arbitrarily specifiable threshold).

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to ask if an element like this (i.e. a subarray like this) exists in testArray, with a TRUE or FALSE result.  I need to do this efficiently.

Comment: Then you don't really mean "for all n", you mean "for some n", since it will never be true that an element exists for all n.

Comment: I meant "for all n > k" in the question description, but you're right, I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
k = 10; 
Cases[testArray, {"StringTwo", n_} /; n > k, 1, 1] != {}

(* True *)
```

Since you are only testing for existence you want to use a method that short-cuts, that is, returns `True` as soon as it finds any instance of what you are looking for. The third and fourth argument of `Cases` specify to only search the 1st level of the list and return the first instance it finds.  The search pattern is written to find a list with a literal `"StringTwo"` followed by a pattern `n` subject to the constraint that `n>k`. Here is a [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html) on the use of constraints with patterns.

Answer (score 2):

For True or False result Catch and Throw is a good option, because it breaks the evaluation  when the condition match. Here is:

```
memberQ[list_List,string_String,value_?NumberQ]:=
   Catch[If[#[[1]]==string&&#[[2]]>value,Throw[#]]&~Scan~list]=!=Null
```

Let's test it

```
memberQ[testArray,"StringTwo",5]
```

> True

### Time Performance

```
bigTestArray=Join @@ Table[testArray, {i, 1, 100000}]

MemberQ[bigTestArray, {"StringTwo", x_} /; x > 5] // AbsoluteTiming
memberQ[bigTestArray,"StringTwo",5]//AbsoluteTiming
Cases[bigTestArray, {"StringTwo", n_} /; n > 5, 1, 1] != {}//AbsoluteTiming
Select[bigTestArray, (#[[1]] == "StringTwo") && (#[[2]] > 5) &] != {} // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000036,True}
> {0.000081,True}
> {0.017640,True}
> {3.542719,True}
> ```

Comment: For me, `MemberQ[bigTestArray, {"StringTwo", x_} /; x > 5] // AbsoluteTiming` is twice as fast as `memberQ`.

Comment: tks @Anon, answer improved.